# Adding vertex and edges to Graph using Boost

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I am new to the boost library and have a couple of queries. From my code below, I'm just trying out the Dijkstra algorithm and its working fine.

I would like to input my own set of vertices and edges from the vectors in the arguments in the function param.(Vertices and Edges). How do I go about doing that?

```
void blossom2(vector<Node*>&vertices, vector<Node*> &clients, vector<Edge*> &edges){
typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float> EdgeWeightProperty;

typedef boost::adjacency_list < boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS,
    boost::no_property, EdgeWeightProperty > Graph;

typedef boost::graph_traits < Graph >::vertex_descriptor vertex_descriptor;
typedef boost::graph_traits < Graph >::edge_descriptor edge_descriptor;
typedef std::pair<int, int> Edge;

// Create a graph
Graph g;

Graph::vertex_descriptor v0 = boost::add_vertex(g);
Graph::vertex_descriptor v1 = boost::add_vertex(g);
Graph::vertex_descriptor v2 = boost::add_vertex(g);

// Add weighted edges
EdgeWeightProperty weight0(5);
boost::add_edge(v0, v1, weight0, g);

EdgeWeightProperty weight1 = 3;
boost::add_edge(v1, v2, weight1, g);

EdgeWeightProperty weight2 = 2;
boost::add_edge(v2, v0, weight2, g);

// Create things for Dijkstra
std::vector<vertex_descriptor> parents(boost::num_vertices(g)); // To store parents
std::vector<int> distances(boost::num_vertices(g)); // To store distances

// Compute shortest paths from v0 to all vertices, and store the output in parents and distances
boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, v0, boost::predecessor_map(&parents[0]).distance_map(&distances[0]));

// Output results
std::cout << "distances and parents:" << std::endl;
boost::graph_traits < Graph >::vertex_iterator vertexIterator, vend;
for (boost::tie(vertexIterator, vend) = boost::vertices(g); vertexIterator != vend; ++vertexIterator)
{
    std::cout << "distance(" << *vertexIterator << ") = " << distances[*vertexIterator] << ", ";
    std::cout << "parent(" << *vertexIterator << ") = " << parents[*vertexIterator] << std::endl;
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

}

Comment: You call the `add_vertex` and `add_edge` functions. What is the question?

Comment: You show only the code that /is working/ (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e37259efe3830bb7) so how are we supposed to magically dream up what you wish to happen?